# C: Detect duplicate integers in a long array

Tags: c, sorting, optimization, duplicates

I've looked at various similar questions on SO and other places but I felt that there are some special circumstances which may warrant a new question.

This is the question:

I have an array of integers which can have upto a billion ints in it. These numbers will be between 1 to 1 billion but there may be missing values. So 32 bits per value should be enough. The only thing I want to do is make sure there are no duplicates. The moment I find the first occurence of a duplicate I make a fuss and exit. This is to be done on a number of files and the files are seldom expected to have duplicates. So the average case will frequently be the worst case too.

I know how to do this very easily in the shell (on the text file I will be reading in the integers from: sort | uniq etc.) and it takes about 13 seconds there. So, hopefully, a pure C smart algo will do better. My idea is that I use a fast (hopefully readily available) sort on the array and iterate computing differences of each consecutive pair. The moment I find a zero I stop and exit.

Here is a toy example:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1003
...
```

I first sort the array and get:
    1001
    1002
    1003
    1003
    1004
    1005
    ...

Then I stop at the fourth line when I see that line3 - line4 == 0.

If all is well, then I exit silently with exit code zero.

These are my requirements / constraints:
1) I am a beginner in C (only a few 100 lines of code under my belt).
2) I will strongly prefer a pure C solution to learn. Standard libraries are okay.
3) If a C++ solution is vastly superior in terms of reduction in programming time, then please suggest that too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What precisely is the question here?  Are you familiar with e.g. `qsort()`?

Comment: What is the maximum range of the integers, i.e. how many bits would you need to represent one uniquely ?

Comment: You can do this very quickly with hashing, O(N) time.  Assuming your values are a reasonable/predictable range.  EX: Something that fits in the int data type.

Comment: You don't need any sorting here. Much simpler to use a bitmap if it will fit the data range and count.

Comment: Also, "if C++ is more efficient...". Thanks for the laugh.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Hey, I am just starting out with the low level languages. So, I don't understand your joke. I'm ready to be insulted if you will explain the joke. :D

Comment: I wasn't insulting you, I was insulting C++.  I suppose there are legitimate reasons to use C++, but improved efficiency over C isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick pseudo code of the hashing solution, so you get the "concept" behind it.  I'll try and make it C, but don't assume it's been compiled and tested.  But it will be close.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_BITS = 32;

bool noDuplicates(const int INPUT[], const int SIZE, const int MIN_VALUE, const int MAX_VALUE) {

    const unsigned int RANGE = (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) / NUM_BITS;  //Use unsigned int, can support wider ranges this way.

    int isPresent[RANGE];// Might need dynamic allocation here, don't know if C supports this type of array initialization

    for(int i = 0; i < RANGE; i++) isPresent[i] = 0;//Probably don't need this loop on most systems.  Aslo, there are faster ways to zero memory.

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

        const int ADJUST_TO_ZERO = INPUT[i] - MIN_VALUE; //adjust our min value to zero index now every possible value should map to an indice in our "isPresent" array
        const int INT_IN_ARRAY = ADJUST_TO_ZERO / NUM_BITS; // Each int represents 32 values, or our bit is hiding in the (VALUE/32)th slot
        const unsigned int BIT_VALUE = 1 << (ADJUST_TO_ZERO % NUM_BITS); // This is identical to 2 ^ (ADJUST_TO_ZERO % NUM_BITS)

        cout << "CHECKING: " << ADJUST_TO_ZERO << " ARRAY INDEX: " << INT_IN_ARRAY << " BIT:" << (ADJUST_TO_ZERO % NUM_BITS) << " INT REPRESENTATION: " << BIT_VALUE << endl;

        if(isPresent[INT_IN_ARRAY] & BIT_VALUE) { //bitwise &, with a value 2 ^ BIT, isolates this "BIT"
            return false;
        }

        isPresent[ADJUST_TO_ZERO / NUM_BITS] += BIT_VALUE; //If we add 2^BIT to an int, we are only adding the value to this to set this "BIT"
    }
    return true; //If we escape the loop above there are no duplicates
}


int main() {
    const int SIZE = 65;
    int array[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    array[SIZE - 1] = 30;

    cout << "RESULT: " << noDuplicates(array, SIZE, 0, 100) << endl;
}
```

Comment: The only problem here is that the `isPresent[]` is going to be 4 GB, which will certainly fail a stack allocation as seen here, and probably even fail using `malloc()` on many systems.

Comment: MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE are parameters, not max possible values of unsigned int.  I also stated that this was an outline of the concept, certainly if your array is large, you would need a dynamic allocation, or potentially a smarter(more space conscious) hashing mechanism.

Comment: He said he had a billion or so values, so that implies a range of a least a billion. C doesn't have compact bool arrays, so that array will be a whole int (4 bytes) per value, i.e., 4 GB. A bitmap would be much better, and even that will be too big for stack allocation.

Comment: The number of values he has says absolutely nothing about the range these values can obtain.

Comment: If he's trying to ensure the list has no duplicates, then yes, it does exactly that.

Comment: I could care less how he hashes them, a bitmap is fine, as I said, I'm outlining the concept...  If he understand how to handle an array of ints of this size, surely he can handle an array of bools of this size.  If he wants to be smart and do a bitmap to save space he is more than welcome.  This is function is simply meant to outline the concept of hashing as it pertains to this problem.  The more values he has, the more time the added space will save him, as surely you realize that sorting a billion values will be very time consuming.

Comment: I have no problem with your algorithm--it's fine. But people learning a low-level language like C need to learn about the importance of low-level issues like memory. I'm just pointing out to the OP that while this code might be instructive, it probably won't be practically usable as is for his job.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can understand what the code is doing. And 4 GB should not be a problem on the system on which this code is supposed to run. Moreover, the numbers are actually such that they will be in the range 1 - 10^9. So that also should not be a problem either. Should I add these particulars to the question?

Comment: Those specifics would help, but if this answer was sufficient it is best just to accept the answer, and take care of the particulars yourself.  No need to spend more time discussing it if you have everything you need.

Comment: Also note, Lee's recommendations about bit mapping are solid.  It will require less memory(like an 1/8th as much I believe, if I'm remembering the size of a bool correctly), and be a little more performant, as there is less chunks of memory moving around.  I didn't double check his method, though I'm sure it's solid, we were having a good discussion about it.

Comment: I am still trying to understand Lee's answer! :D The only reason I did not mark your's as the accepted answer is because I was thinking if I can understand Lee's answer and if it is more efficient, everything else being equal, perhaps I should accept his answer?

Comment: It depends on which criteria you find more important, simplicity/speed or memory.  They are both answers.  One is more optimized for memory, one is more optimized processor.  Bit shifting will save you some memory, but these are till wasted processor cycles, and wasted assignments.  The idea is that a bool is 7 wasted bits, to store the information.  A 32 bit integer can store 32 1s and 0s.  If you wish to optimize for memory footprint, this is very valuable.  If you don't care, I believe my solution may actually be faster, his solution is using 3*10^9 extra assignments.

Comment: With a computer with reasonably large cache, ram, etc... this will likely slow it down more than the additional loading from memory would.  Ultimately the concept is identical.  If you can support the memory, I would recommend going with the solution you understand.  If one solution is faster than the other, the difference would be negligible... assuming a modern computing environment.  This is truly just a concern about memory.

Comment: You might try benchmarking each solution though.  My comments about the memory footprint creating a negligible difference, speed wise, is certainly architecture dependent.  And optimizing for memory, when you're dealing with such large amounts, is frequently a better optimization speed wise as well.  I don't think either solution is production ready... I could provide you a bit mapping solution that you might understand better, and doesn't involve as many wasted assignments, if you'd like.

Comment: I would love any help. Thanks for the offer. If you can provide me any pointers to understand what the bitmap solution is actually doing, I'd be much grateful. :)

Also, may I run a very naive idea through you. Since we are using the bool only to track whether we have seen an entry before, can we not use a char to save these states - 0 or 1. This should be lenient on the memory requirements as well? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: No, they will suffer fromt he same issue, both char and bool are 1 byte.  I have a bit map solution almost ready.  It's no faster than Lee's, but it is more conceptually friendly, and I believe will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: I added a full "main.cpp" type file.  The bit implementation part is all C friendly, I just through in C++ for the stdout.  This probably isn't the fastest way to do this, Lee's solution is better, but this should be conceptually friendly, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: The bit map solution appears to be about 5 - 10 percent faster.  Not particularly significant, and is likely architecture dependent.  The benchmark interested me, so I did it, thought I'd share the results.

Comment: Hey Chris, I understand. Also, I have already implemented the algorithm in my solution. One of the test cases had 7.5 M lines. The code finished in 2 seconds. :) That is awesome! I'm waiting to see if it can be made even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the range of your values is, but assuming it's the range of 32-bit integers, a bitmap array would be 512MB, which would fit on most modern machines without much trouble.  Try something like this:

```
/* Assumes 32-bit ints */
int verify_unique( <data source> ) {
    unsigned int *bitmap = calloc(128 * 1024 * 1024, 4);
    if (!bitmap) { <error> }

    while ( <more input> ) {
        unsigned int value = <next value>;
        unsigned int index = value >> 5;
        unsigned int mask = 1 << (value & 0x1f);

        if (bitmap[index] & mask) {
            <found duplicate>
            break;
        }
        bitmap[index] |= mask;
    }
    free(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Lee, I have never used bitshifting before. I tried to understand this by googling around but I could not. Can you provide a few comments to nudge me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will definitely try to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) to sort your array, then do the link3 minus link4 method. should be efficient enough for the purpose.

Comment: Doing the "link3 minus link4"-method is not needed when using counting sort. Even sorting the array is useless, you only need the count-array of counting sort. The other steps of the algorithm are not required for this issue. The values in the count-array will indicate if there are duplicate values or not.

Comment: You know, i read that wiki article and was thinking the same, but i wasnt sure. thank you for confirming.